# Looping Through Txt Files using VBA - DIR() issue

Tags: excel, textbox, vba

I have the following code where I am trying to modify some Txt files in a specific folder. I first want to check that the Loop works. However when I run the macro the code can only read the first file and then there is a runtime 5 error at strFileName = Dir(). I am not sure what the problem is. The only issue I can think of is that I am moving the code between two module sheets. The folder location is being saved in a txt box in Sheet 1 of an excel workbook.

```
Sub Txt_File_Loop()
Public TextFile As String
Dim FolderLocation As String
Dim strFielName As String
Dim SaveLocation As String
'Location is present in a Text box
FolderLocation = Sheets(1).FolderLocationTXTBX.Text
strFileName = Dir(FolderLocation & " \ * ")
Do Until strFileName = ""
TextFile = FolderLocation & "\" & strFileName
Module2.Macro1
strFileName = Dir() 'ERROR is Here
Loop

End Sub

Sub Macro1()
Dim x As String
Open TextFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, textline
x = x & textline
Loop

Close #1
MsgBox x

End Sub
```

Comment: uhh.. how does your code compile? You're missing a `Loop` statement to close the `Do While...`  You also have the `Open TextFile` line *inside* the loop, so how can it know where the End Of File (`EOF`) is before opening it?  Your first portion doesn't appear to be part of any subroutine at all.  There's no way your error is happening on `strFileName = Dir()` based on the code you've provided...

Comment: `strFileName = Dir(FolderLocation & " \ * ")` you mean `strFileName = Dir(FolderLocation & "\")`? Also what does `debug.print FolderLocation` give you?

Comment: I meant to add a Loop statement in macro1.

Comment: debug.print FolderLocation just gives me the link to the folder. E.g C:\Folder\SubFolder. I tried removing the * but it did not work, I still get the same error.

Comment: `strFielName` should probably be `'strFileName`.

Comment: ... or more general: include `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module, modify the code until it compiles, then tell us what error you are left with.  As-is, there's lots of other more important things wrong with the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these modifications. They seem to correct several things and run through well.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Txt_File_Loop()
    Dim FolderLocation As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim SaveLocation As String
    'Location is present in a Text box
    FolderLocation = Sheets(1).FolderLocationTXTBX.Text   'Environ("TMP")
    strFileName = Dir(FolderLocation & "\*.txt")
    Do Until strFileName = ""
        Debug.Print FolderLocation & "\" & strFileName
        Module2.Macro1 FolderLocation & "\" & strFileName
        strFileName = Dir() 'ERROR is Here
    Loop
End Sub

Sub Macro1(sFPFN As String)
    Dim x As String, textline As String
    Debug.Print sFPFN

    Open sFPFN For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        x = x & textline
    Loop

    Close #1
    MsgBox x

End Sub
```

I passed the folder and filename name across as a string-type parameter. Also, I don't know why you had the extra spaces in `(FolderLocation & " \ * "` ; I tightened that up. There were a few misspellings and undeclared variables; these can be avoided with `Option Explicit`¹ at the top of the module code sheet. Get into the practise of standard indentation with your code. It certainly improves readability if nothing else.

---

¹ <sub>Setting **Require Variable Declaration** within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page will put the **[Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each newly created code sheet. This will avoid silly coding mistakes like misspellings as well as influencing you to use the correct variable type in the variable declaration. Variables created on-the-fly without declaration are all of the variant/object type. Using **Option Explicit** is widely considered 'best practice'.</sub>

Comment: Thank you I will check if this works on Monday at work.

Comment: It works now. Thank you, I will use Option Explicit in my macros going forward.